# How to make a Persistent Navigation Drawer in Android?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer, drawerlayout

I have search a lot but manage the Navigation easily but at this time need to Implement Persistent Navigation Drawer.

https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-behavior

`Please let me know the process to Manage or Sample Tutorial of **Persistent Navigation Drawer** shown in below Image. LinkedIn Android Application is using the same navigation drawer.`

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Persistent Navigation drawer? Do you have any tutorial of `Persistent Navigation drawer`

Comment: That's not a `NavigationDrawer`. To do that you need to implement it yourself or you can use some library which supports this.

Comment: @Ranjith : I did not found yet. Thanks

Comment: @XaverKapeller: https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-behavior

Comment: @XaverKapeller : Please have a look on this. Thanks

Comment: Yes that's the `NavigationDrawer` spec, what do you want me to see?

Comment: Could you give me some hint, how can I start with it. Thanks
@XaverKapeller

Comment: With what? What do you want to do?

Comment: K..so you are asking a navigation drawer that is always displayed and cannot be hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implement "Persistent Navigation Drawer" via ViewPager and works fine as what I need.

Just use width as 0.8f  in PagerAdaper/FragmentPagerAdapter

```
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (position == 0) {
        return .8f;
    }
    return 1f;
}
```

Comment: Could you post a complete exemple here ? Thanks !

Comment: No, I've ended using another solution.

Comment: @slaadvak: Could you please share your way, how you achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

My XML file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerView"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/list_background"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My activity:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ....
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    RelativeLayout drawerView;
    RelativeLayout mainView;
    ....

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        ............. //
        .............//
        drawerView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerView);
        mainView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                mainView.setTranslationX(slideOffset * drawerView.getWidth());
                mDrawerLayout.bringChildToFront(drawerView);
                mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();


            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);}
}
```

The code inside onDrawerSlide will get you what you want.

Comment: This solution doesn't justify the question. It just shifts the main view outside screen while the drawer opens. What is requested (based on material docs) is to have both views functioning at the same time.